# Postfix do not send emails to googleapps email

Tags: postfix, smtp, ubuntu-14.04, smtpd

I am using postfix on one of the server from where I can't send emails from command line. below is the extract of command `postconf -n`

```
postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = tempfail
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = ip-10-1-1-47, ip-10-1-1-47, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = ip-10-1-1-47
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = example.com
non_smtpd_milters =
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [smtp.exampleapp.com]
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_milters =
smtpd_use_tls = no
```

Below are the postfix logs. Logs say email is sent but I never received email.

```
Oct 18 19:41:53 ip-10-1-1-47 postfix/smtpd[10425]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Oct 18 19:41:53 ip-10-1-1-47 postfix/smtpd[10425]: B7719421A8: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Oct 18 19:41:53 ip-10-1-1-47 postfix/cleanup[10428]: B7719421A8: message-id=<1476819713.1934825492@ip-10-1-1-47>
Oct 18 19:41:53 ip-10-1-1-47 postfix/smtpd[10425]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Oct 18 19:41:53 ip-10-1-1-47 postfix/qmgr[4955]: B7719421A8: from=<monit@staging.example.com>, size=620, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 18 19:41:53 ip-10-1-1-47 postfix/smtp[10429]: B7719421A8: to=<robots@example.com>, relay=smtp.exampleapp.com[52.6.223.177]:25, delay=0.07, delays=0.04/0.01/0.01/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as C150F4800D9)
Oct 18 19:41:53 ip-10-1-1-47 postfix/qmgr[4955]: B7719421A8: removed
```

Any suggestions would be a great help.  Thanks
Note: I have checked my inbox thoroughly.

Comment: Your mail wasn't sent to Google. It was sent to .... something running on AWS?

Comment: Yes This instance is on aws. and I am trying to understand the flow of my postfix mailing server. Somehow when I send mail from command line I get above in my postfix logs. But there is nothing with IP 52.6.223.177 in my account @Michael Hampton

Comment: Why did you configure Postfix to send email there, then?

Comment: These configurations are already there and I am trying to understand why I am not able to send email to myself from there. What do you suggest to enable sending email from command line.

Comment: Who knows? All I can tell is that Postfix is configured to send mail to some relay host. If you didn't do it, you should probably talk to whoever did it.